# Going to two URLs in html

Tags: html

On begin.html, I've written some code like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="test.php">Proceed</a>;
```

This makes the link open in a new tab/window. Simultaneously, I want to go to test2.php from begin.html by clicking on the same link. 
So, basically, at the end of my operation, one tab shows test2.php and the new tab shows test.php.
Is it possible?

Comment: You’ll have to use JavaScript; it’s not possible with HTML only.

Comment: @bfontaine I'm using PHP and html...so is it possible using PHP?

Comment: No, unless you generate JS code from PHP and inject it in the HTML.

Comment: @bfontaine um, I didn't really get that. Could you please give the code snippet? I'm confused.

Comment: I added it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have test2.php in root folder as test.php. you can try it this way. Don't forget to add your javascript code inside a script tag.

```
<script>
function OpenNewPage() {
  var win = window.open('test2.php', '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
</script>

<a target="_blank" href="test.php" onclick="OpenNewPage();">Proceed</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need JavaScript to do that; and even with it it’s very likely the browser will block the second window thinking it’s a popup:

```
<button id="b">Click here</button>
```

```
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function() {

    window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");
    window.open("https://www.bing.com", "_blank");

}, false);
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdahcx7y/).